# Knockout layout and binding with transposed rows

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, x-editable

I am new knockout.js and I am using x-editable and knockout-x-editable for binding a data entry form that looks as follows,

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: employee">
      <td class="span1">
        <span data-bind="visible: $index() == 0">Firstname</span>
      </td>
      <td class="span1 protected">
        <span data-bind="editable: Firstname, editableOptions: { name:'Firstname', pk: ID"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: employee">
      <td class="span1">
        <span data-bind="visible: $index() == 0">Lastname</span>
      </td>
      <td class="span1 protected">
        <span data-bind="editable: Lastname, editableOptions: { name:'Lastname', pk: ID"></span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The rows should be transposed as below

```
Firstname  | Firstname1  | Firstname2 |  Firstname3
Lastname   | Lastname1   | Lastname2  |  Lastname3
```

I would like to use knockout templates, is there any better way to achieve this? Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to mention what the problem is.

Comment: Tomalak, is there a better way to achieve this, see that I am looping through the list multiple times to list the elements, I am looking for a better way to achieve this, without redundant loops may be with a ko  templates even better,

Answer (score 0):

Looping through the same list twice is what you need to do anyway. Using a template will not give you a real benefit here.

This is because you'd have to inform the template *which part* of the employee it needs to render and there is no native way of doing that. Templates are meant to render one single type of object. Using the same template to render different properties on the same type of object goes against their use case. (The alternative, namely using *two different* templates, goes against your intention of simplification.)

You could explore [custom bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html), but I would tend to say "that's over-engineering" and I doubt that it will be worth the effort in this case.

I'd use a virtual element (an HTML comment that looks like `<!-- ko ... --> <!-- /ko -->`) instead of your `visible` binding, but other than that my approach would look roughly the same as yours:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="span1">Firstname</th>
      <!-- ko foreach: employee -->
      <td class="span1 protected">
        <span data-bind="
           editable: Firstname, 
           editableOptions: { name: 'Firstname', pk: ID }
        "></span>
      </td>
      <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
    <tr data-bind="foreach: employee">
      <th class="span1">Lastname</th>
      <!-- ko foreach: employee -->
      <td class="span1 protected">
        <span data-bind="
          editable: Lastname, 
          editableOptions: { name: 'Lastname', pk: ID }
        "></span>
      </td>
      <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

If you have many more properties you want to render into a table, you could alter your data model:

```
function ViewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.employee = ko.observableArray([/* many employees here */]);
  self.properties = ['Firstname', 'Lastname', 'Email', 'Phone', 'Jobtitle'];
}
```

and

```html
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: properties">
    <tr>
      <th class="span1" data-bind="text: $data"></th>
      <!-- ko foreach: $root.employee -->
      <td class="span1 protected">
        <span data-bind="
           editable: $data[$parent], 
           editableOptions: { name: $parent, pk: ID }
        "></span>
      </td>
      <!-- /ko -->
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that binding contexts can be nested: `foreach: properties` creates a new context, and the inner context (`foreach: $root.employee`) can refer to the outer one via the `$parent` variable. This way you can re-use the inner setup for different properties of the employee (and you can define the order of the output in your code).

`$parent` refers to the parent *data*, in this specific case that is the strings that are in the `properties` array.